# Querying and updating Redshift through AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-step-functions

I am using a step function and it gives a JSON to the Lambda as *event*(object data from s3 upload). I have to check the JSON and compare 2 values in it(file name and eTag) to the data in my redshift DB. If the entry does not exist, I have to classify the file to a different bucket and add an entry to the redshift DB(versioning). Trouble is, I do not have a good idea of how I can query and update Redshift through Lambda. Can someone please give suggestions on what methods I should adopt? Thanks!

Edit: Should've mentioned the lambda is in Python

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this use case is you can write the Lambda function by using the Java run-time API and then within the Lambda function, use a **RedshiftDataClient** object. Using this API, you can perform CRUD operations on a Redshift cluster.

To see examples:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/redshift/src/main/java/com/example/redshiftdata

If you are unsure how to build a Lambda function by using the Lambda Java run-time API that can invoke AWS Services, please refer to :

[Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

This example shows you how to develop a Lambda function using the Java runtime API that invokes AWS Services. So instead of invoking Amazon S3 or Rekognition, use the RedshiftDataClient within the Lambda function to perform Redshift CRUD opertions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention the language for lambda. It's supposed to be in Python. I have been trying out psycopg2, but unsure if it is the path I should try